# Is there some equivalent to setInterval in the ZK server structure?

Tags: refresh, zk

I'm trying to make a process that will refresh my Chart from time to time. In `Javascript` the answer comes in my mind: `setInterval()` + ajax call. How can I do this with ZK?

I looked at the [Client Side Programming](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming) but didn't find anything that solves this requirement.

In the Server Side, it seems that I can fire events with `Events.echoEvent()`, doing this repeatdly have any downside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is the [`Timer`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Timer) component. It fires events after a specified delay.